# What is CreateNewAttribute in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to know what is CreateNewAttribute and how it works?

Comment: Praveen, C# is a programming language. It has no libraries. Anything like CreateNewAttribute may be used _in_ a C# program, but will not be _from_ C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing "in C#". But maybe you mean [Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.CreateNewAttribute](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.objectbuilder.createnewattribute(BTS.10).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

It's used by ObjectBuilder. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.irm.se/blogs/eric/archive/2006/08/21/Dependency-Injection_3A00_-CreateNew-Attribute.aspx) explaining the attribute and usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to ObjectBuilder - dependency injection container.